# retrieving substrings which are not matched by re.findall

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume we have a regular expression `exp` and want to find all occurrences of this pattern in a string `s`. This can be easily done with

```
import re
m=re.findall(exp,s)
```

But now we also want to have all the substrings in between the matches.

The first part of the question is: What is the best/simplest way to do it?

The second part of the question is: Is it possible to get matches **and** the in-betweens in one sweep through the string `s`, that is without matching the regex twice?

Comment: Why not use `re.split`? And do not do that in 1 operation. Regexps are meant to match, not *not to match*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, I think `re.split` works for this:

```
>>> re.split("a(?=b)", "ababba")
['', 'b', 'bba']
```

As a solution to part 2, I think you might be able to do something like this:

```
exp2 = re.compile(exp)
unmatched = []
prev_match_end = 0
for match in exp2.finditer(s):
    unmatched.append(s[prev_match_end: match.start()])
    prev_match_end = match.end()

# Deal with unmatched text after last match:
unmatched.append(s[prev_match_end:])
```

Now you have all the matches and unmatched text.

Comment: Thank you! It is a simple and elegant solution for the first part of the question I haven't thought of. But I would really like to cut the second sweep...

Comment: awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a lot!